# Haskell The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression error

Tags: haskell

Hello please can someone tell me where this error comes from ? 
The error is 
DKA-2-MKA.hs:39:5:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      argv <- getArgs

i checked intendation already and it didnt helped

```
 import System.Environment
 import System.Console.GetOpt
 import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )

 data Options = Options { optI :: Boo , optT :: Bool } deriving (Show)

 defaultOptions :: Options
 defaultOptions = Options { optI = False, optT = False }

 options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Options)]
 options = [ Option ['i']    ["I"]
             (NoArg (\ opts -> opts {optI = True}))
             "I is true"
           , Option ['t']    ["T"]
             (NoArg (\ opts -> opts {optT = True}))
             "T is true"
           ]

 programOpt :: [String] -> IO (Options, String)
 programOpt argv = 
     case getOpt Permute options argv of
         (o, n, [] ) -> return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n) 
         (o, _, [] ) -> ioError $ userError $ exactlyone ++ usageInfo header options
         (_, _, errs) -> ioError $ userError $ concat errs ++ usageInfo header options
     where
         header = "Usage [OPTIONS...] filename"
         exactlyone = "One input"


 main :: IO ()
 main = do
     argv <-getArgs
```

Comment: You can't have a `<-` arrow in the last line of a `do` block - this is technically to do with how it "desugars" to uses of the `>>=` operator, but actually it doesn't make much sense however you look at it. `getArgs` is an "action" which reads the command-line arguments, then the `<-` binds the `argv` variable to the resulting list, but you need to "do something" with that list. If you explain what your actual indention is then we can help you with how to write it correctly - it's really not clear from this code what you want.

Comment: oh thank you that helped :)

Comment: Put `return ()` on the next line after `argv <- getArgs`

Comment: Adding `return ()` makes it type check, but the resulting `IO` action doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: FYI: I collapsed the definitions of `Options` and `options` to one line each just to make your definition of `main` visible without needing to scroll.

Answer (score 2):

> DKA-2-MKA.hs:39:5: The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression argv <- getArgs

- `39:5` indicates the error is at line 39, column 5. Which looks like `argv <- getArgs`
- an "expression" is a bit of code that is syntactically valid, has a type, and can be evaluated. Examples of expressions include

  - `let x = 1 in x + 2`
  - `if b then x else y`
  - `5`
  - `return ()`
- examples of *not expressions* include:

  - `(1`
  - `let x = 5`
  - `if b then x`

`argv <-getArgs` is *not* an expression, it's a dangling bit of syntax that doesn't make sense on its own; you can't ask ghci `:t argv <-getArgs`.

In order to understand *why* the last line in a `do` block must be an expression, search "desugaring do notation haskell" on this site or elsewhere (maybe someone else can recommend a specific resource). This will also be in any intro haskell book.